# mass field creation & migration

Tags: deployment, ide, migration-tool, workbench

Actually, I already have a salesforce org where I have some custom objects & fields. Now I want to create the same objects and fields(including checkbox, formula fields nearly 100) in another org. Manually creating will consume a lot of time. So anybody can suggest what I can do to migrate these object & fields?

I have gone through the ant tool but I'm not able to understand the process.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool.htm

Comment: Even if you don't use ANT, a metadata api retrieve() and deploy() call is definitely the way to go. I believe the Eclipse "Force.com IDE" and [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) would both work if you don't want to use ANT.

Comment: thanx @martin but i have never used these things so can you explain or else can you share any link with me so that i can clear my confusion.

Comment: [How to use workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench#Metadata)

Comment: @geek_sfdc,

Please go through below link and you will good example.

http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/06/ant-setup-for-salesforce-migration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Change sets are Available in Enterprise, Unlimited, Free, and Database.com Editions.
Make sure you have following permissions for your profile in new org. If you still dont see it then log a case with Salesforce.

Also change sets deploy metadata within same org stacks..means that you can deploy changes between a specific org's sandbox and production. it will not work if you want to move metadata from Org A to Org B

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/app_deployment/units/app_deployment_changesets